# Delphi XE3 not compile/debug

Tags: delphi, compilation, delphi-xe3

I installed Delphi XE3 on my computer, I create a new VCL Form Application and I tried to run it, just for test, and I had a F2039 saying that cannot create the file. The folder is not read-only, I did not installed any component or anything, I just have one other Delphi IDE on my machine (BDS 2006) and on it runs okay.

Could anyone help me?

Comment: Is an instance of the program already running and you're trying to start it again? That'd give the message that it can't write to the exe file.

Comment: No. I'm running just one instance. I tried closing by the task manager or restart the system but the problem persists. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe the IDE is trying to write to a folder you have no write access to. Can you check the program settings for its output path. Is there an EXE there?

Comment: Yes, I Do have write acess to the folder and there's a EXE file, but with 0KB Thanks!

Comment: Chances are what file is open already. Examine with Sysinternals' `handle` utility.

Comment: Try disabling your AV software

Comment: David! Thanks a Lot dude! That worked! #NoobFeelings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess, confirmed by your comment, is that your anti-virus software is blocking Delphi from writing the executable file. It is of course possible that your Delphi is infected, but more likely this is just a false positive.

If this is a false positive, and if the anti-virus software will not relent, you may need to find a different anti-virus software.